# Hide specific GridViewColumn in listview based on condition

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have listview with 10 `GridViewColumn`s, each column should be visible at runtime based on a condition, of course the column can be collapsed by setting the width to 0. but how to do this programaticaly let say if `P[1].TestResult = "NA"` then the column should collapsed.

```
<GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="P-1">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock x:Name="P1" Text="{Binding P[1].TestResult}" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Style="{StaticResource CellStyle}" />
        </DataTemplate>

    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>

<GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="P-2">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock x:Name="P2" Text="{Binding P[2].TestResult}" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="20"  Style="{StaticResource CellStyle}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>

<!-- ... -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that if `TestResult` of any item in a column is `NA`, it should be hidden. You could expose a computed `bool` property that implements the condition. You could probably use Linq's `Any` method for this, but I cannot assume your types, so you have to implement it yourself.

```
public bool IsAnyP1TestResultNotAvailable => /* ...check if any test result is NA */.
```

Then you could use one of the numerous converters from [C#/WPF: Make a GridViewColumn Visible=false?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1392811/6181599) to hide the specific column by binding to this property. Whenever `TestResult` changes (e.g. in its setter), you could raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the computed property to update the bindings in the user interface.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i was searching :)