# How to hide GridViewColumn using Data trigger in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

**Hiding using Width would only hide it Visually, element is still there, what about screen reader.**

- I have GridViewColumn, where I want to show and hide based upon Property, How can I hide it.
- Currently, I have using the [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392811/c-wpf-make-a-gridviewcolumn-visible-false), However I want to do it using Property. How can I achieve it?

```xml
<GridViewColumn
                                CellTemplate="{StaticResource KeyTamplate}"
                                Header="{res:Label {x:Static res:enum.LabelName}}"
                                HeaderTemplate="{DynamicResource KeyHere}"
                                 />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the `Width` property to a `double` property of the view model that you set to `0` to hide the column:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="header..." DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Property}"
     Width="{Binding ColumnWidth}" />
```

**View Model:**

```
public double ColumnWidth { get; set; } = double.NaN;
```

If you set the `ColumnWidth` property dynamically, you should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter to notify the view.

Since you can't style a `GridViewColumn`, using a `DataTrigger` is not an option.

But you shouldn't really need one as you can set the source property directly in your view model and handle all the logic there.

Comment: Yes, I know this approach will work, but the tricky part is , I need to do it using ```DataTrigger```.

Comment: You can't style a `GridViewColumn` so using a `DataTrigger` is not an option. But you shouldn't need one as you can set the view model property directly.

Comment: Just implement your logic in the view model instead of using a `DataTrigger` in the view.

Comment: What about setting ```DataTrigger``` to tamplates of ```cellTamplate``` and ```HeaderTamplate```.

Comment: This won't affect the width or visibility of the column itself. And why do you want to to this in the view where you have a view model that you can set directly? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I agree, its just because I was trying it to complete in this way. However now I think working with ```width``` is better approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254179/discussion-between-nexo-and-mm8).

Comment: Btw, what if someone is using screen reader to read, what will this hidden approach has affect?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Comment: Hey, sorry, its not an issue, that the main reason, I have just updated my question.

Comment: A screen reader cannot read an invisible element.

Comment: We are setting width to 0, means element is still there.

Comment: Depends on how you define "still there". It's not visible for a screen reader or a user.